# How to get all css-styles from a dom-element using Selenium, C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My task is to create a minimized css-file from a web-page. And so I need values from [all css-properties](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/default.asp) from all dom-elements.
But I don't know: How to get all computed css-styles from a specific dom-element?

I have the following code:

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArguments("headless");

var browser = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);

var url = "https://example.com";
browser.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

var domElement = browser.FindElement(By.TagName("html"));
```

And I want:

```
var styles = domElement.GetComputedCssStyles();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `getCSSValue` method of `IWebElement`. For example to get the background color of a element you can try the following code.

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArguments("headless");

var browser = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);

var url = "https://example.com";
browser.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

var domElement = browser.FindElement(By.TagName("html"));
var color = domElement.GetCssValue("background-color");
```

May you can try the following javascript code using selenium C#;

```
string properties = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return window.getComputedStyle(arguments[0],null).cssText", domElement);
strArr = properties.split(";")

for (count = 0; count <= strArr.Length - 1; count++)
{
    console.log(strArr[count]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need all the set css-values. I don't need a certain css-value.

Comment: There are mulitple css styles are applied for a element. better to get the one which we want

Comment: My task is to create a minimized css file from a web-page. And so I need values from all css properties.

Comment: That will be taken care by Front end UI designer. I think you are trying to do reverse engineering.

Comment: @Palindromer I have added another solution to get all the computed styles of a element. It may be helpful for you. please try and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

To get all the computed css-styles from a specific dom-element you can use the following line of code:

- **C#**:

  ```
  ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("var items = {}; for (index = 0; index < arguments[0].attributes.length; ++index) { items[arguments[0].attributes[index].name] = arguments[0].attributes[index].value }; return items;", myElem);
  ```
- Sample (*Java*) Code Block:

  ```
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
  WebElement myElem = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
  System.out.println(((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("var items = {}; for (index = 0; index < arguments[0].attributes.length; ++index) { items[arguments[0].attributes[index].name] = arguments[0].attributes[index].value }; return items;", myElem).toString());
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  {aria-autocomplete=list, aria-haspopup=false, aria-label=Search, autocomplete=off, class=gsfi lst-d-f, dir=ltr, id=lst-ib, maxlength=2048, name=q, role=combobox, spellcheck=false, style=border: medium none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; height: auto; width: 100%; background: transparent url("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw%3D%3D") repeat scroll 0% 0%; position: absolute; z-index: 6; left: 0px; outline: medium none currentcolor;, title=Search, type=text, value=}
  ```