# How to get child property value of a element property using selenium webdriver, NUnit and C#

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, getcomputedstyle, getpropertyvalue

I am testing websites using selenium webdriver and I am having difficulties getting the value of a property that is a child of another property.  For me, this 2nd/child level is always coming back as null.

When trying to get a value of an upper level attribute/property it is working fine with the following code:

```
return Element1.GetAttribute("baseURI");
return Element2.GetAttribute("innerText");
```

Those above return the text/string that I am expecting.  However if I try and get the value of a child property like the following:

```
return Element3.GetAttribute("style.cssText");
return Element4.GetAttribute("style.fontWeight")
```

I am getting null.  When I view the DOM/properties of the elements above, I do see the values that they have.

```
cssText: "font-weight: bold;"
fontWeight: "bold"
```

If I right click on the properties from within the Developer Toolbar and choose "Copy Property Path", I get the following:

```
style.cssText
style.fontWeight
```

So I believe the problem is how I am referring to the child property by assuming what I am copying from the developer toolbar is correct.  I have tried other delimiters other than a period, but I am still having now luck.

I'm trying to figure out the syntax to return the value stored in -

```
object.style.fontWeight
```

I've tried:

```
parent.child.GetCSSValue("css"), parent-child.GetCSSValue("css")
parent.child.GetAttribute("attrib"), parent-child.GetAttribute("attrib")
parent.child.GetProperty("prop"), parent-child.GetProperty("prop")
```

These all come back as null or empty.string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all css-styles from a dom-element using Selenium, C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50601267/how-to-get-all-css-styles-from-a-dom-element-using-selenium-c-sharp)

Comment: this is not a duplicate (I'm not asking for all values) and the link shared doesn't even have a favorable approved answer

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the syntax to return the value stored in - object.style.fontWeight

is it: 

parent.child.GetCSSValue("css"), parent-child.GetCSSValue("css")
parent.child.GetCSSValue("css"), parent-child.GetCSSValue("css")

or: 

parent.child.GetAttribute("attrib"), parent-child.GetAttribute("attrib")
parent.child.GetAttribute("attrib"), parent-child.GetAttribute("attrib")

or even:

parent.child.GetProperty("prop"), parent-child.GetProperty("prop")
parent.child.GetProperty("prop"), parent-child.GetProperty("prop")

These all come back as null or empty.string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you were pretty close. To retrieve the `cssText` and `fontWeight` you can use the [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) and then use [`getPropertyValue()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/getPropertyValue) to retrieve the **style** and you can use the following solution:

```
IJavascriptExecutor jse = (IJavascriptExecutor)driver;
String cssText_script = "var x = getComputedStyle(arguments[0]);" +
        "window.document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(x,null).getPropertyValue('cssText');"; ";
String fontWeight_script = "var x = getComputedStyle(arguments[0]);" +
        "window.document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(x,null).getPropertyValue('fontWeight');"; ";
string myCssText = (string) jse.ExecuteScript(cssText_script, Element3);
string myFontWeight = (string) jse.ExecuteScript(fontWeight_script, Element4);
```

*Note*: You need to induce *WebDriverWait* along with the [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm) as [ElementIsVisible](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_ElementIsVisible.htm) method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript's `getComputedStyle` and `getPropertyValue` to get inherited style attribute value:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;

string fontWeight = (string) js.ExecuteScript("return window.getComputedStyle(arguments[0]).getPropertyValue('fontWeight')", element);

string cssText = (string) js.ExecuteScript("return window.getComputedStyle(arguments[0]).cssText", element);
```

More details about `getComputedStyle` you can find [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle). Everything else about css and selenium you can find in [How to get all css-styles from a dom-element using Selenium, C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50601267/how-to-get-all-css-styles-from-a-dom-element-using-selenium-c-sharp)

Comment: Thanks for that link, but I would still like to see how you would reference a child property.  I'll see if I can implement what you are saying in .NET.