# GetAttribute in Selenium VBA for style

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, getcomputedstyle

I am working on selenium in VBA and I have stored a variable"post" to store all the occurrences of a specific element like that

```
Dim post As Object

Set post = .FindElementsByCss("#DetailSection1")
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To post.Count
    Debug.Print post.Item(i).getAttribute("style")
Next i
```

I need to extract the style value from the elements

```
<div id="DetailSection1" style="z-index:3;clip:rect(0px,746px,32px,0px);top:228px;left:0px;width:746px;height:32px;">
</div>
```

Also I need to print in the immediate window the innerHTML and when I used `getAttribute("innerHTML")`, it doesn't work for me
Any ideas

Comment: Shouldn't you use getting the element by Id instead of getting it by CSS?

Comment: The id in my case is not unique. I have 22 of this id

Comment: I can't remember but isn't Selenium basic method Attribute("") rather than getAttribute? getAttribute is for a node within nodeList rather than webElement. IIRC but confirmation would be good.

Comment: Thank you very much for the awesome hint. That worked for me `Debug.Print .FindElementByCss("#DetailSection1").Attribute("outerHTML")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getAttribute("style")` should work but you have to induce a waiter for the element to be present/visible within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp).

```
Debug.Print post.Item(i).getAttribute("style")
```

---

Precisely, to extract value of the style attributes from the elements you can use the [`getCssValue()`](https://github.com/danwagnerco/selenium-vba/blob/master/wrapper/WebElement.cs#L135) method as follows:

```
Debug.Print post.Item(i).getCssValue("z-index")
Debug.Print post.Item(i).getCssValue("top")
Debug.Print post.Item(i).getCssValue("left")
Debug.Print post.Item(i).getCssValue("width")
Debug.Print post.Item(i).getCssValue("height")
```

---

### `getAttribute("innerHTML")`

`get_attribute("innerHTML")` can be used to read the innerHTML or the *text* within any node / [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139)

> You can find a detailed discussion in [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to get child property value of a element property using selenium webdriver, NUnit and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54853126/how-to-get-child-property-value-of-a-element-property-using-selenium-webdriver/54856077#54856077)
- [How can I verify text is bold using selenium on an angular website with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56662720/how-can-i-verify-text-is-bold-using-selenium-on-an-angular-website-with-c-sharp/56663636#56663636)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This throws an error. And also what about `innerHTML `?

Comment: @YasserKhalil Checkout the answer update and let me know if any questions.

Comment: I used `get_attribute("innerHTML")` and also `getAttribute("innerHTML")` and both throws an error. I don't know what's wrong?

Comment: Can you have a look at the HTML, please? https://pastebin.com/nu0dLvch

Comment: @YasserKhalil Updated the answer. As the elements are react elements, you need to induce some wait for the element to be present/visible before extracting the style.

Comment: `Object doesn't support this property or method`, this is what I got my friend.

Comment: This worked for me `Debug.Print .FindElementsByCss("#DetailSection1")(1).CssValue("top")`. I am working on VBA and I think there is difference between python and VBA in that. How can I get printed the innerhtml? I can't get that work.

Comment: @YasserKhalil Hmm, I don't have a VBA env setup but I know the VBA codebase which I have linked for your reference. Glad you got it working.

Comment: Thank you very much. The last point: How can I get printed the innerhtml? I can't get that work

Comment: @YasserKhalil The element for which you have provided the html don't have a any `innerHTML` or _text_. So in this case it will always return a _blank_

Comment: So is there a way to print the HTML part for that element?

Comment: @YasserKhalil Possibly you are looking for `getAttribute("outerHTML")`

Comment: Can you try that on your side? neither `innerHTML` or `outerHTML` works!!

Comment: @YasserKhalil Going by [`getAttribute(string attributeName)`](https://github.com/danwagnerco/selenium-vba/blob/master/wrapper/WebElement.cs#L110) possibly you simply need **`Text`**