# How to get style for a particular class in Selenium C#

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, getattribute

I am trying to get style properties from an element using selenium  which displays as below.

```
element.style {
    left: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 414px;
    top: 0px;
}
    .Content
    {
        min-height: 500px;
        padding-top: 10px;
    }
```

Using the below code retrieves only the element style properties "left: 0px;margin: 0px;width: 414px;top: 0px;"

```
 var style = webelement.GetAttribute("style");
```

How to get all the styles specific to Content class ?

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the value of [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139)'s *style* and *Content* you can use the following solutions:

- *style* using [GetAttribute("style")](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_GetAttribute.htm) as follows:

  ```
  var style = webelement.GetAttribute("style");
  ```
- *Content* using [GetCssValue("Content")](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_GetCssValue.htm) as follows:

  ```
  var style = webelement.GetCssValue("Content");
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to convert #ffffff to #fff or #fff to #ffffff while asserting the background color rgb(255,255,255) returned by Selenium getCssValue("background")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54767206/how-to-convert-ffffff-to-fff-or-fff-to-ffffff-while-asserting-the-background)
- [How can I verify text is bold using selenium on an angular website with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56662720/how-can-i-verify-text-is-bold-using-selenium-on-an-angular-website-with-c-sharp/56663636#56663636)
- [GetAttribute in Selenium VBA for style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62339724/getattribute-in-selenium-vba-for-style/62343379#62343379)
- [How to get background-image from inline css using selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59103063/how-to-get-background-image-from-inline-css-using-selenium/59103600#59103600)