# Is there a way to get copy styles of elements with python selenium in chrome

Tags: python, css, selenium, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

In this picture we see we can get styles from `copy > copy styles` from chrome manually but is there anyway to do this with `selenium`

[image]

In this link [get CSS Value of specific element with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50601573/11692124) but there is no way of doing it for all css rules applied [update: this way is unwanted even it brings all css rules because it doesnt bring dynamic values like `20vw` instead brings hard coded computed values like `240.6px`]

Besides in [get all the computed css-styles from a specific dom-element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50602487/11692124) unlike the result(`Console Output:`), I cant reproduce the result. for i.e. in page `http://loader.to/` if we capture element which has `body > div.container > div > div > div:nth-child(3) > label` css selector and put it in `elementSelectedWithCssSelector`

with the code line of

`driver.execute_script('var items = {}; for (index = 0; index < arguments[0].attributes.length; ++index) { items[arguments[0].attributes[index].name] = arguments[0].attributes[index].value }; return items;', elementSelectedWithCssSelector )` we get `{'for': 'link'}` but we were supposed to get css rules as the `Console Output:` in the SE answer were provided.[update: computed styled always has dynamic values problem mentioned before]

Or with `elementSelectedWithCssSelector.get_attribute("style.cssText")` I tried to get styles which returned nothing

[update]: I have tried some approach like `Jortega`s answer, but it seems the JS only can bring the `computed styles`

So my question are (answering one if it is equal to css rules the '`copy > copy styles` from chrome' returns is enough, without dynamic values problem):

1. is there any way of automating the `copy > copy styles` from chrome with selenium preferably or other tools?
2. can it be done with `chrome extension tools`, I mean can I get access to these `copy > copy styles` with learning how to code an extension for chrome?
3. [update: unwanted because of computedStyle-dynamicValue problem]or can we get all style rules with the ways were mentioned in the links I have provided here or any other way?
4. can we get css rules with `get_attribute` in selenium?

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of how to get the css properties if the stack overflow link on the banner of this page.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
import sys
import json
sys.path.append('D:\\Path\\To\\geckodriver.exe')
service = Service('D:\\Path\\To\\geckodriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service)

driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72669869/is-there-a-way-to-get-copy-styles-of-elements-with-python-selenium-in-chrome")

def get_css_properties(element):
    properties_dictionary = {}
    properties = driver.execute_script('return window.getComputedStyle(arguments[0], null);', element)
    for property_ in properties:
        properties_dictionary[property_] = element.value_of_css_property(property_)
    return properties_dictionary

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Stack Overflow']")))

css_props = get_css_properties(element)
print(json.dumps(css_props, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

Comment: actually I have tried sth similar to this with selenium but the thing is I dont want `computed styles` because its hard code values like `360.4px` instead of `20vw`, anyway thanks for providing this answer.